# Ubuntu Mint 19 32-bit - PyCharm / SDK install

Tags: linux, sdk, pycharm, virtual-machine, 32-bit

I want to install PyCharm Community on 32-bit Ubuntu Mint 19 on VM. 
How and where do I download 32-bit version of PyCharm for Linux?

The one that is downloadable from https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=linux comes with jre64 and I am getting a LafManager error on startup. Renaming this folder doesn't help to avoid the issue. 
According to JetBrains documentation, 32-bit PyCharm shoud come without SDK, and SDK should be downloaded separately and installed as plugin or at first startup.